# Como puedo vender productos desde un sitio web?

Tags: php, html

Que tal, soy nuevo en programacion web y tengo un proyecto de un sitio web de ventas, que temas debo investigar?

Comment: Hola Fernando. Tienes varias preguntas en el sitio. Sabes que esta clase de preguntas no son aceptadas y son cerradas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes empezar usando un CMS (Content Management System) como Prestashop.
Estos CMS te permiten tener lista tu tienda en cuestión de días y a medida que vayas teniendo exito, puedes desarrollar o comprar modulos que se adapten a tus necesidades específicas.

Answer (score 1):

Veo por los tags que pusiste a tu pregunta que piensas hacer tu sitio web con php. Lo mejor es que no reinventes la rueda. Actualmente hay muchos proyectos open source que son precisamente sitios de venta. Uno de los mas populares es PrestaShop https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop escrito en php. Ahora bien si es un ejercicio academico y la idea es hacer un sitio desde cero te sugiero investigar los siguientes temas:

1. Sesiones y cookies: tus usuarios necesitan registrarse e iniciar sesion e incluir productos en el carrito de compras. Para todo esto debes usar cookies.
2. Base de datos SQL: evidentemente debe usar una base de datos para almacenar los productos que vas a vender.
3. Peticiones ajax: tu sitio debe funcionar con peticiones ajax. Para optimizar la experiencia de usuario, la pagina no debe cargarse con cada accion del usuario.

Comment: Por favor no responder las preguntas basadas en opiniones.